# WPF ListBox - how to displays values from datatable with multiple columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am having a problem, I have a datatable **data** with 3 columns(ID,NAME,QUANTITY), I want to bind it with a ListBox, and make ListBox shows values from column NAME and QUANTITY,otherwise when I double click in a selected item,it will send ID value, here is my XAML:

```
<ListBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,0,0,0" Name="ListBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="600" Width="321">
                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListBox1Item_DoubleClick" />
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListBox.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate x:Key="listBoxTemplate">
                                <DockPanel >
                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding NAME}"
                  DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                  Margin="5,0,10,0" Width="100"/>

                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding QUANTITY} "   Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.Resources>
                    </ListBox>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
...
            ListBox1.ItemsSource = data.DefaultView;
            ListBox1.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
...
```

But it does not show anything, something wrongs? please help! thanks for reading this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the ListBox.ItemTemplate.
At the moment you are defining a template with a key, that template is not being used anywhere.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DockPanel >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NAME}" FontWeight="Bold"
                       DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                       Margin="5,0,10,0" Width="100" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding QUANTITY}" FontWeight="Bold"
                       Foreground="Green" />
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```